# How to extract from a google sheet cells that do not contain a keyword so that it concatenate with it the corresponding data in the first row & column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, extract, data-manipulation, array-formulas

I have an [exemple spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wQ7_qUxuUDWDl61VWxN7Or0y81lRHE6n8YZryaGg0dE/edit?usp=sharing) where i want to extract from the sheet "Survey" the cells that do not contain "OK" or "ok" and list them in the sheet "Extract" so that it takes into account the corresponding data in the frozen first row and column.

Example :

[image: Exemple]

The extract would give in the first cell of the "Extract" sheet : `(149,163)-G:AD`

Would someone be able to help me with that please ? If at all possible.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Find non ok's

```
function wierdData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const r1 = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const c1 = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const ro = r1.findIndex(e => e != '') + 1;
  const co = c1.findIndex(e => e != '') + 1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(co, ro, sh.getLastRow() - co + 1, sh.getLastColumn() - ro + 1).getValues();
  let o = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if(isNaN(c) && c.toLowerCase() != "ok") {
        o.push(`(${r1[ro + j - 1]},${c1[co + i - 1]})-${c}`);
      }
    })
  })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs))
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  let oA = o.map(e => [e]);
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,1).setValues(oA)
}
Execution log
11:33:56 AM Notice  Execution started
11:33:56 AM Info    ["(153,168)-S:AB","(149,163)-G:AD","(150,157)-G:CB"]
11:33:57 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Sheet0:

|  | 145 | 146 | 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152 | 153 | 154 | 155 | 156 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Exemple sheet |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 175 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 174 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 173 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 172 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 171 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 170 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 169 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 168 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | S:AB | ok | ok | ok |
| 167 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 166 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 165 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 164 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 163 | ok | OK | OK | OK | G:AD | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 162 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 161 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 160 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 159 | ok | OK | OK | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 158 | ok | OK | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 157 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | G:CB | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 156 | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok | ok |

Sheet1:

| (153,168)-S:AB |
| --- |
| (149,163)-G:AD |
| (150,157)-G:CB |

Comment: Sorry I had the numbers reversed at first

Comment: Thanks, it worked on my test sheet, however when i transpose it to my main sheet, i get the following error : 
TypeError: c.toLowerCase is not a function
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:12
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:11
wierdData @ Code.gs:10

Comment: I added the code to post it in column one. It just needed to be formated as: `[[],[],[]]`

Comment: Ok, so it was still failing with  TypeError: c.toLowerCase is not a function  so i added toString() before the .toLowerCase and that worked.
Now the last thing for it to be perfect would be to ignore empty cells, apologies i forgot to leave some cells empty in the exemple sheet.

Comment: Please share your main sheet I don't think I can debug it without seeing it.  It appears that you have more than just strings in your data

Comment: I made a small change.  Try it again

Comment: If this does not work then I suggest modifying your example to reflect an environment more descriptive of your actual data.

Comment: i don't see the change ? it says last modified 25mn ago.
I updated the exemple sheet with empty cells in the 4th row

Comment: Sorry the if in the main loop has been changed and I guess I forgot to save it the first time.  I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula({"NOT OK";QUERY(FLATTEN(IF((Survey!A:A="")+(Survey!B:M="")+(Survey!B:M="ok")+(TRIM(Survey!B:M)="");;"("&Survey!B1:M1&","&Survey!A:A&")-"&Survey!B:M));"WHERE Col1 Is Not Null ORDER BY Col1")})`

This formula will produce the header "NOT OK" (which you can change from within the formula as you like) and all results that are not listed as "OK" (any capitalization) in the Survey sheet. Results will be listed in the requested format.

Essentially anything where Col A in the Survey sheet is blank OR where Row 1 in the Survey sheet is blank OR where the rest is not some form of "OK" OR where any cell in the original grid is blank will be replaced with null. The rest will be concatenated with the Col-A and Row-1 data as requested.  `FLATTEN` will form one column from that grid of results. And `QUERY` will remove null entries and place the final results in ascending order. If you'd prefer the results to run in *descending* order, just add  `DESC` after `Col1` at the end of the `QUERY` clause.